# How to subtract 18 months from the current date in MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

Select all babies wich were born in the last year and a half?

```
SELECT name FROM Babies
WHERE   YEAR(Born_date) > YEAR (DATE())-1.5
```

Is this sql query valid for such thing or  should i involve the MONTH function as well?
I would like to retrieve all the kids(newborns) which were born in the last year and a half so in the last 365+ (365/2) days.

Comment: Please tag the DB system that you are using

Comment: Give us your RDBMS name (Oracle, MySQL, etc ...) also your table design and a description of what u want to achieve will be most helpful.

Comment: Have you tried it? You could have tested it in the time it took you to post here.

Comment: i just can t try it because we havent got actual data, so basically i can test this and see the output. We ve just been given  a ER model on paper and queries on paper.

Comment: Aww,  you guys are killing me!  Put this on hold and I only got 10 pts because he didnt tag the RDBMS in the OP.  It was pretty clear he just wanted to subtract 18 months from the current date in sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MS-ACCESS, DateADD should work.  Try something like this:

```
select name 
from babies where birthdate >= DATEADD('m', -18, Date())
```

Comment: `getdate()` is not a valid function in Access SQL, and `month` will either be interpreted as a table field or a parameter. `DateAdd("m",-18,Date())` would work much better.

Comment: @gord-thompson, You are correct.  I forgot getdate() didnt work.  nice job.